# having issue with my signup using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am making an application in which user signup using rest `api` . `api` working successfully but i am having issue when the user enters same email second time for user registration the application crashing. i am not under standing how to make check which tells email already exist. here is my code where i am registering a user.

```
private void userSignup(){

    String user_type = String.valueOf(radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    String directory_type = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String username = edit_username.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = edit_email.getText().toString().trim();
    String first_name = edit_firstname.getText().toString().trim();
    String last_name = edit_lastname.getText().toString().trim();
    String phone = edit_Phone.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = edit_password.getText().toString().trim();
    String confirm_password = edit_retypePassword.getText().toString().trim();



    if (username.isEmpty()){
        edit_username.setError("User Name is Required");
        edit_username.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        edit_email.setError("Enter a valid Email");
        edit_email.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (first_name.isEmpty()){
        edit_firstname.setError("First Name is Required");
        edit_firstname.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (last_name.isEmpty()){
        edit_lastname.setError("Last Name is Required");
        edit_lastname.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (!Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches()){
        edit_Phone.setError("Enter a valid Phone NO.");
        edit_Phone.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (password.isEmpty()){
        edit_password.setError("Password required");
        edit_password.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (password.length() < 6){
        edit_password.setError("Password should be atleast 6 characters");
        edit_password.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (!confirm_password.equals(password)){
        edit_retypePassword.setError("Error in Password matching please check");
        edit_retypePassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (confirm_password.isEmpty()){
        edit_retypePassword.setError("Retype password is required");
        edit_retypePassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(user_type) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(directory_type) ||
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(username) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) ||
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(first_name) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(last_name) ||
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(phone) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(password) ||
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(confirm_password)){

        mRegProgress.setTitle("Registering User");
        mRegProgress.setMessage("Please wait while we create your account !");
        mRegProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mRegProgress.show();

    //    RetrofitUtil.createProviderAPI().createUser(user_type ,directory_type , username , email , first_name , last_name , phone , password , confirm_password).enqueue(SignupUser(this));


        retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance()
                .getApi().createUser(user_type ,directory_type , username , email , first_name , last_name , phone , password , confirm_password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                mRegProgress.dismiss();
                String s  = response.body().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Signup_Activity.this , "User Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Signup_Activity.this , t.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Here is my `api` call...

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("user/do_signup")
    Call<ResponseBody> createUser(
            @Field("user_type") String user_type,
            @Field("directory_type") String directory_type,
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("first_name") String first_name,
            @Field("last_name") String last_name,
            @Field("phone") String phone,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("confirm_password") String confirm_password

    );
```

here is the log ....

```
01-22 18:07:39.096 21582-21603/? E/AudioALSAPlaybackHandlerBase: openPcmDriver(), pcm_start(0xea013780) fail due to cannot start channel: Broken pipe
01-22 18:07:39.156 21582-21603/? E/AudioALSAPlaybackHandlerBase: -getHardwareBufferInfo pcm_get_htimestamp fail, ret = -1, pcm_get_error = cannot start channel: Broken pipe
01-22 18:07:39.159 21582-21603/? E/AudioALSAPlaybackHandlerBase: -getHardwareBufferInfo pcm_get_htimestamp fail, ret = -1, pcm_get_error = cannot start channel: Broken pipe
01-22 18:07:39.168 21582-21603/? E/AudioFlinger: getNextBuffer, get null buffer
01-22 18:07:39.235 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 1147 num clients 15
01-22 18:07:39.235 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=800555 Rx=1296057
01-22 18:07:39.235 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: notifying of data activity 2
01-22 18:07:40.236 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 1147 num clients 15
01-22 18:07:40.236 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=800556 Rx=1296059
01-22 18:07:40.236 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: notifying of data activity 3
01-22 18:07:40.437 1009-1292/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=2427 BSSID=40:ee:dd:ac:a9:e8 RSSI=-56 "HUAWEI-XkKR"WPA_PSK
01-22 18:07:41.237 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 1147 num clients 15
01-22 18:07:41.237 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=800556 Rx=1296059
01-22 18:07:41.237 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: notifying of data activity 0
01-22 18:07:42.238 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 1147 num clients 15
01-22 18:07:42.240 1009-1009/? E/WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=800556 Rx=1296059
01-22 18:07:42.626 8508-8508/com.example.saadhashmi.docdirect E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.saadhashmi.docdirect, PID: 8508
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.saadhashmi.docdirect.Activities.Signup_Activity$4.onResponse(Signup_Activity.java:222)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
01-22 18:07:42.674 1009-15376/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
01-22 18:07:42.808 1009-2455/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
01-22 18:07:42.878 1009-2117/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
01-22 18:07:42.911 2570-3200/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
01-22 18:07:43.089 8722-8722/com.example.saadhashmi.docdirect E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
```

Comment: can you show the log and you need to specify that response in your api side if email already exist or not

Comment: @Ashish i have edit the question please check

Comment: your log says your sending null value try to log each field and check which field your missing

Comment: @Ashish this happend when i try to create a user with the email that already exist

Comment: check line number 222 as log suggests that field is null. -> at com.example.saadhashmi.docdirect.Activities.Signup_Activity$4.onResponse(Signup_Activity.java:222), and to be precise look into this class -> com.example.saadhashmi.docdirect.Activities.Signup_Activity$4.onResponse(Signup_Activity.java:222)

Comment: @Ashish here is am just printing the response like this ... String s  = response.body().toString();

Comment: remove that line and put Log there so you can check what is your response

Comment: ok just let me check

Answer (score 2):

You should check your response that was successful or has error or occurred  some issue on server. you should check your [http response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and subject of that.

`response.code()` gives you this http response code

and `isSuccessful()` function check this code is in range 200~300 that means successful response!

```
 public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    mRegProgress.dismiss();
    if(response.isSuccessful()){
         String s  = response.body().toString();
         Toast.makeText(Signup_Activity.this , "User Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
         Log.i("Error ",response.errorBody())
    }                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when receiving response you should always check the response you are getting is null or not and then only print your response, else it will throw NPE. change your code like following ->

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        mRegProgress.dismiss();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                String s = response.body().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Signup_Activity.this, "User Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
        else {
            log.d(TAG, "Null Response Body");
        }
      }
      else{
            log.d(TAG,"response UnSuccessful");
      }
    }
```